# Validating given date (Ex-14/2/2012) is in format mm/dd/yyyy in dynamics ax x++

Tags: validation, date, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

In a if loop if the date exists then i need to validate if date is in mm/dd/yyyy format. 
if i give 14/1/2015 it should give error because mm cannot be 14. mm max value should be 12. 
Can anyone help me.Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`str2Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa554244.aspx) you can specify dmy order.

- 1: day
- 2: month
- 3: year

It returns `0` if date parsing failed.
Example:

```cs
date d = str2Date('14/1/2015', 213);

// check for error
if (!d)
{
    throw error("Yourd message...");
}
```